Estimating mixed model with identical response value but different covariate values within a pair
Say we have a dataset with individuals. Each individual performed a task, either in solo or with another individual (variable condition), and we measured the performance of the whole group, that is, the individual or the pair (variable score). 
In other words, we have one value of score for individuals in solo, and twice the same value for individuals in a pair.
We considered individuals in solo as forming a pair on their own, leading to the variable pair.
The Condition (solo vs paired) was between-subject, thus an individual either performed the task in solo or with another individual, leading to a single score for each individual (which is shared among the individuals of a pair).
We also measured a covariate individually, that is, we have one value of cov for each individual.
The dataframe looks like this:
> head(df, 12)
id  pair score cov condition
1  pair1     3   6      solo
2  pair2     6   4      pair
3  pair2     6   3      pair
4  pair3     3   3      solo
5  pair4     5   3      pair
6  pair4     5   4      pair
7  pair5     3   5      solo
8  pair6     5   5      pair
9  pair6     5   3      pair
10 pair7     4   3      solo
11 pair8     4   5      pair
12 pair8     4   4      pair

Although the score is not repeated, I was wondering whether it made sense to fit a mixed model given that individuals have different values of cov within a pair.
However, estimating a model such as:
lme4::lmer(score ~ condition * cov + (1 | pair))
results in a failure to converge.
I have a feeling that this is to be expected, given the redundancy in the score variable. That said, I cannot quite get the reason why.
I read somewhere that the residual variance could be confounded with the random effect variance. But shouldn't the residual variance be different than the random variance to account for the observed difference in cov ?

It is not a problem per se to have variables that vary at different levels. cov is a "first level" covariate because it varies at the level of individual, and condition is a "second level" covariate because it varies at the level of pair. Some "pairs" have only one individual so you are right to suspect that as the reason for lack of convergence. It may also be due to a relatively small dataset that you are trying to use to estimate a lot of parameters. How many rows are in the dataset?

I might suggest using a Bayesian approach so that you can put an informative prior on the random effect variance component which will help the model converge.

What happens if you remove the interaction between condition and cov?

@qdread Thanks ! I tried using simulated data with N ranging from 120 to 120k, facing the same issue. But when I think about it, in this setup, the ratio N individuals / N pairs remains the same no matter the N (i.e., the total number of pairs will always be N * 2/3 because two 'pairs' are created every three individuals). Thus, the ratio of observations / parameters to estimate remains the same as well no matter the N, meaning that if the issue arises from this ratio there is not much I could do.

@mdewey I tried your suggestion but unfortunately it leads to the same issue.

"We considered individuals in solo as forming a pair on their own, leading to the variable pair." That seems strange. In my opinion, the grouping ID of the random effect should be the individual. I think I would try and modify the dataset to have one solo observation and two pair observations for each individual and then model score ~ condition * cov + (1 | individual). Currently, you have never repeated measures for solo tasks and never any ID that did both solo and pair tasks. But that doesn't reflect the actual experimental setup, where everyone did both solo and pair tasks.

@Roland I will modify to clarify, but Condition is between-subject, so each individual did either the task solo or in a pair with another individual. Thus, we only have one score for each individual (and in a pair, this score is identical between the two individuals), making it impossible to put the individual as the random effect.

Depending on what question you are trying to answer, there's a different modeling approach I would consider. It has the following idea:

Every individual has a certain skill at the task. If they are doing the task solo that's all that matters for how good the score is expected to be.
When people work together as a pair.

Unless theirs something specific about the task that makes it matter whether you're the first or the second person in the pair (e.g. #1 is the "manager" and #2 is the "worker" or something like that), it shouldn't matter whether you're the first person in the pair or not.
The most basic idea could be that what matters is the average skill of the team and whether you work as a pair or solo.


Similarly, the covariates should kind of matter the same whether it's for the first person or the second, you'd think. So, you could either just force the coefficient to be the same (which would if it's a linear effect mean that you could take the average and just have a coefficient for that, or you could reflect that it might matter if covariates differ between the people in the pair and use a coefficient for the higher and lower value, or for the mean and the difference).
On the other hand, we shouldn't double-count records by creating a record with person #1 first and then with the other person first.

One idea to approach this is a multi-membership model (see also this discussion regarding covariates), to use brms notation, the model could look like this:

score ~ condition + lower_cov + higher_cov + (1|mm(person1, person2)) (where you'd make person1 and person2 the same, if they do it solo), or perhaps
score ~ condition + mean_cov + diff_cov + (1|mm(person1, person2)) or perhaps
score ~ condition + mean_cov + diff_cov:condition + (1|mm(person1, person2)) (reflecting that there not being a difference in skill would matter differently whether you're in a pair or solo), or perhaps
score ~ condition + (1 + mmc(cov_person1, cov_person2) | mm(person1, person2)) (see documentation regarding multi-membership covariates here).

You can likely come up with many more variants of this.
The multi-membership term mm() basically models the the latent unobserved (but estimated from the scores) skill of the subjects and when they are in a pair averages them. If you wanted something more complex, like accessing these latent skill variables and modeling a coefficient that estimates the effect of combining two people with similar or different latent skill, then this simple notation won't do it any longer (but you could write your own Stan code). As far as I'm aware the mmc(cov_person1, cov_person2) would declare cov_person1 to go with person1 and cov_person2 to go with person2, I've never used that with brms before, but I assume it ensures the covariates have a common coefficient around which the individual coefficients per person can vary.

This is a very nice answer to go around the issue, thank you! I'll wait a bit to see if there is a more 'explanation-oriented' answer popping up (still want to understand exactly why this happens), but if not I'll mark your post as answer for sure.
